# Ace editor keeps reverting to read only mode

Tags: flash

I've successfully embedded the ACE editor into my site but it keeps reverting to read only mode. When I put the cursor into the editor the first time it works and I can type text but if I move the mouse and place the cursor in another location I can no longer type. When I check the properties of the editor it appears that read only has been set to true.

**Update**:
It appears it may not have to do with read only (only it's exhibiting the same behavior). I noticed that when I put the cursor in the editor it accepts the text I type. When I set the cursor to another location the textarea position is updated and from then on any text I type results in a "ding" sound like you can't type here type of sound. It's like a windows alert message.

Anyway, I set one of the div containers to a different display or position type then all of a sudden it's working properly but then the editor is in the wrong position.

If I click outside of the editor and then back into the editor then I can type again... at least until I move the cursor like I described before.

Here is before (working):

```
<div style="position: absolute; background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); border: 0px none; overflow: auto; display: block; left: 316px; top: 239px; width: 1074px; height: 140px;" id="editor0"><div id="iframe_editor0" frameborder="0"><div class=" ace_editor ace_nobold ace-crimson-editor" id="editor" style="display:block;position:absolute;top:0px;left:0px;right:0px;bottom:0px;height:100%;"><textarea style="bottom: 92px; height: 16px; width: 7.2px; right: 1019.6px;" spellcheck="false" wrap="off" class="ace_text-input"></textarea><div style="display: none;" class="ace_gutter"><div style="margin-top: 0px; height: 172px; width: 34px;" class="ace_layer ace_gutter-layer"><div class="ace_gutter-cell " style="height:16px;">1</div><div class="ace_gutter-cell " style="height:16px;">2</div><div class="ace_gutter-cell " style="height:16px;">3</div><div class="ace_gutter-cell " style="height:16px;">4</div></div><div style="top: 32px; height: 16px;" class="ace_gutter-active-line"></div></div><div style="left: 0px; right: 15px;" class="ace_scroller"><div style="margin-top: 0px; width: 1066px; height: 172px;" class="ace_content"><div class="ace_layer ace_print-margin-layer"><div style="left: 580px; visibility: hidden;" class="ace_print-margin"></div></div><div class="ace_layer ace_marker-layer"><div class="ace_active-line" style="height:16px;top:32px;left:0;right:0;"></div></div><div style="padding: 0px 4px;" class="ace_layer ace_text-layer"><div class="ace_line" style="height:16px"><span class="ace_meta ace_tag">&lt;</span><span class="ace_meta ace_tag ace_tag-name">div</span>&nbsp;<span class="ace_entity ace_other ace_attribute-name">style</span><span class="ace_keyword ace_operator">=</span><span class="ace_string">"position:relative;width:640px;height:500px;font-family:Arial;font-size:12px;margin:0&nbsp;auto;left:8px;top:14px;background-color:#FFFFFF;"</span><span class="ace_meta ace_tag ace_r">&gt;</span></div><div class="ace_line" style="height:16px"></div><div class="ace_line" style="height:16px"><span class="ace_meta ace_tag">&lt;/</span><span class="ace_meta ace_tag ace_tag-name">div</span><span class="ace_meta ace_tag ace_r">&gt;</span></div><div class="ace_line" style="height:16px"></div></div><div class="ace_layer ace_marker-layer"></div><div class="ace_layer ace_cursor-layer ace_hidden-cursors"><div style="left: 47.2px; top: 32px; width: 7.2px; height: 16px;" class="ace_cursor"></div></div></div></div><div style="height: auto; width: auto; top: -100px; left: -100px; visibility: hidden; position: fixed; overflow: visible; white-space: nowrap;">X</div><div style="width: 20px; height: 140px;" class="ace_scrollbar"><div style="height: 64px;" class="ace_scrollbar-inner"></div></div></div></div></div>
```

And after repositioning the cursor / clicking the mouse in a new location (not working):

```
<div style="position: absolute; background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); border: 0px none; overflow: auto; display: block; left: 316px; top: 239px; width: 1074px; height: 140px;" id="editor0"><div id="iframe_editor0" frameborder="0"><div class=" ace_editor ace_nobold ace-crimson-editor ace_focus" id="editor" style="display:block;position:absolute;top:0px;left:0px;right:0px;bottom:0px;height:100%;"><textarea style="bottom: 92px; height: 16px; width: 7.2px; right: 1019.6px;" spellcheck="false" wrap="off" class="ace_text-input"></textarea><div style="display: none;" class="ace_gutter"><div style="margin-top: 0px; height: 172px; width: 34px;" class="ace_layer ace_gutter-layer"><div class="ace_gutter-cell " style="height:16px;">1</div><div class="ace_gutter-cell " style="height:16px;">2</div><div class="ace_gutter-cell " style="height:16px;">3</div><div class="ace_gutter-cell " style="height:16px;">4</div></div><div style="top: 32px; height: 16px;" class="ace_gutter-active-line"></div></div><div style="left: 0px; right: 15px; overflow-x: hidden;" class="ace_scroller"><div style="margin-top: 0px; width: 1066px; height: 172px;" class="ace_content"><div class="ace_layer ace_print-margin-layer"><div style="left: 580px; visibility: hidden;" class="ace_print-margin"></div></div><div class="ace_layer ace_marker-layer"><div class="ace_active-line" style="height:16px;top:32px;left:0;right:0;"></div></div><div style="padding: 0px 4px;" class="ace_layer ace_text-layer"><div class="ace_line" style="height:16px"><span class="ace_meta ace_tag">&lt;</span><span class="ace_meta ace_tag ace_tag-name">div</span>&nbsp;<span class="ace_entity ace_other ace_attribute-name">style</span><span class="ace_keyword ace_operator">=</span><span class="ace_string">"position:relative;width:640px;height:500px;font-family:Arial;font-size:12px;margin:0&nbsp;auto;left:8px;top:14px;background-color:#FFFFFF;"</span><span class="ace_meta ace_tag ace_r">&gt;</span></div><div class="ace_line" style="height:16px"></div><div class="ace_line" style="height:16px"><span class="ace_meta ace_tag">&lt;/</span><span class="ace_meta ace_tag ace_tag-name">div</span><span class="ace_meta ace_tag ace_r">&gt;</span></div><div class="ace_line" style="height:16px"></div></div><div class="ace_layer ace_marker-layer"></div><div class="ace_layer ace_cursor-layer"><div style="left: 47.2px; top: 32px; width: 7.2px; height: 16px; opacity: 0;" class="ace_cursor"></div></div></div></div><div style="height: auto; width: auto; top: -100px; left: -100px; visibility: hidden; position: fixed; overflow: visible; white-space: nowrap;">X</div><div style="width: 20px; height: 140px;" class="ace_scrollbar"><div style="height: 64px;" class="ace_scrollbar-inner"></div></div></div></div></div>
```

The previous code is what is inside the body tag.

**Update 2**
It seems that if the editor is on top of a Flash / Flex app it is causing the problem. I set the Flash / Flex app to half the height and the area that no longer had the Flash app beneath it worked correctly. Again, this is only happening in Firefox Mac. In Safari on Mac it works correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem occurred with any text area, not specifically a text area used by the Ace Editor.

If you place an HTML text area over any Flash application, type some text into that HTML text area, then click another location in the text field (move the cursor) it exhibits the same behavior. That behavior being that no additional text is entered and a beeping sound occurs.

A newer version of Flash Player or a newer version of Firefox has fixed the problem. I don't know which version it was fixed in but it was around Sept 27, 2015.